# Evaluating $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^n x ~\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find the general formula for the following:

$$I_n = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^n x ~\mathrm{d}x$$

I remember doing it a while back but for the life of me, I can't remember right now. I have the following:

\begin{align}
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^n x ~\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\big]^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 + \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^{n-2}x~\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

Now if we evaluate the first portion the it becomes $0$ and the second portion, since we have a not-so-nice $n-2$ we'll make that equal to $p$ so $p = n-2$ and $n = p+2$

\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^{n-2}x~\mathrm{d}x \\
\implies &\left(\frac{p+1}{p+2}\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^{p}x~\mathrm{d}x \\
\implies &\left(\frac{p+1}{p+2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{p}\sin^{p-1}x\cos x\big]^\frac{\pi}{2}_0+\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^{p-2}x~\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
\implies &\left(\frac{p+1}{p+2}\right)\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^{p-2}x~\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align}

The last two steps I'm not too sure about but I think they are correct. That being said, I don't quite understand how to go about from here. Am I supposed to now considered even and odd cases for $p$?

Can someone point in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is known as [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks! I had no clue; it may have been easier if I had this `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get to $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^n x ~\mathrm{d}x = \big[-\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\big]^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 + \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^{n-2}x~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{n-1}nI_{n-2}$$you therefore have $$I_n = \dfrac{n-1}nI_{n-2}=\frac{(n-1)(n-3)}{n(n-2)}I_{n-4} =\ldots$$ By calculating explicitly $I_0$ and $I_1$ you can get the solution.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. How will calculating $I_0$ and $I_1$ give me the solution? Can you please expand a little more? I'm having a serious brain freeze.

Comment: Try to write $I_{2n}$ in terms of $I_0$ and $I_{2n+1}$ is terms of $I_1$ (and use induction to prove what you found).